# What's the best way to implement gmail style "undo" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, gmail, undo, revert

I think it important to have an "**undo**" method ala **gmail** when destroying records instead of displaying an annoying popup that says, "*Are you sure?*".

The way that I've implemented this is to have a "deleted_at" timestamp column in the model which gets timestamped when **destroy** method is called

```
def destroy
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  @foo.update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now)
  ...
end
```

To **revert/undo** I'll just set the same column to nil

```
def revert
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  @foo.update_attribute(:deleted_at, nil)
  ...
end
```

I'll just have to add a condition to filter off "deleted" foos when I call the find method. Perhaps set a cron or background task to really destroy "deleted" foos after some time.

Works for me and easy to implement but I'm curious as to if there's a better way to implement this feature? Maybe there's a plugin or gem that provides this that I don't know about?

Comment: Do you really care when it was deleted? Isn't a flag sufficient?

Comment: Yeah I don't really care when it was deleted for now but that knowledge might be useful down the line. Anyway I think timestamps makes a good flag.

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment. However, one possible problem by pre-empting needs like that is that it might trick other developers into searching for where that (timestamp) information is currently used. When it isn't actually used somewhere, it represents a loose thread, which is often frustrating and time consuming for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed some plugins that can be found at [Agile Web Development](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins).

Here are the links and summaries for the plugins which seem to match your description:

1. [Acts as Paranoid](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_paranoid): Make your Active Records "paranoid." Deleting them does not delete the row, but set a deleted_at field. Find is overloaded to skip deleted records.
2. [Acts as soft deletable](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_soft_deletable): Provides the ability to soft delete ActiveRecord models.

Comment: Seems like Acts As Paranoid might have some problems with future versions of ActiveRecord since it overrides the find method.

Acts As Soft Deletable looks good. I'm just wondering if the deleted_table gets out of sync how do I resync it?

Have you used any of them before?

Comment: No, but in the description of soft deletable it says that it has helper methods built in to keep them in sync

Comment: A brief review of the two makes it seem like Acts as soft deletable would be the better choice, both for the method used and the fact that it appears to be better maintained.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file [here](http://github.com/alto/redline/tree/ed884597354762572b4112ef4d3d13a13d051faa/lib/acts_as_deletable.rb) that seems to do what you're requiring, but personally I think there must be something out there that automatically filters out deleted records unless you specifically include them.  That way they really would appear deleted unless you include a parameter or a named scope that re-includes them.

Unfortunately, I haven't written one and spare time is limited, but it shouldn't be that hard, should it?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the deleted items into a separate collection (or table, or whatever) - then anything that looks in the original list will see that it's been deleted, and you can deal with the new list when it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

[PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) does this nicely. There is a good [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail) on it, although it is a little old now. I know this question was asked quite a while ago but I stumbled upon it out of curiosity and thought I should reference a nice up to date way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

responsibility chain pattern

```
class Action
{
  Perform(context);
  Undo(context);
}
```

Comment: This is very vague and doesn't give me any idea on how to actually do the undo.  what is the context?  how does it interact with the database?